# Cross-version upgrade, cnosdb panic

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

Cross-version upgrade, cnosdb panic

version：cnosdb 2.3.0, revision = 954d3b6f581e74b520f4a964700832cf39545b20--->cnosdb 2.3.4, revision 508f669fb723daa5195f05e8b020ebf3f322064d

In version 2.3.0, I have been writing monitoring data all the time. Now I see that cnosdb has been updated to version 2.3.4, and panic occurred during the upgrade

the log as follow:

```
2023-11-27T16:44:45.377828955+08:00  INFO meta::store::state_machine: METADATA WRITE: /data_version :438446
2023-11-27T16:44:45.377898978+08:00  INFO meta::store::state_machine: METADATA WRITE(ver: 438446): /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":2973017837568,"time":1701074685,"status":"Healthy"}
2023-11-27T16:44:49.726553797+08:00  INFO tskv::index::ts_index: Recovering index binlog: '/data1/monitor/monitor/data/db/data/cnosdb.usage_schema/3/index/_000001.binlog'
2023-11-27T16:44:49.743362186+08:00  INFO tskv::index::ts_index: Recovered index dir '/data1/monitor/monitor/data/db/data/cnosdb.usage_schema/3/index', incr_id start at: 17
2023-11-27T16:44:49.747921953+08:00  INFO tskv::index::ts_index: Recovering index binlog: '/data1/monitor/monitor/data/db/data/cnosdb.cadvisor/9/index/_000001.binlog'
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IndexErr { source: DecodeSeriesKey { msg: "Invalid serde message: Invalid serde message: io error: unexpected end of file" } }
Location: /home/bca/code/cnosdb/tskv/src/kvcore.rs:176

  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
                                ⋮ 9 frames hidden ⋮                               
  10: tskv::kvcore::TsKv::open::{{closure}}::h71e7970eb8837785
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  11: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::create_tskv::{{closure}}::hd654f378b27e126f
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  12: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::build_query_storage::{{closure}}::h69cf83ce825dcdfb
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  13: cnosdb::main::{{closure}}::hb2d636eb57c52d9d
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  14: cnosdb::main::h2edd31c0a621e3c2
```

Are the two versions incompatible?